# Running command line results in module not found as user postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu, sudo, wal-e

Im trying to run a package `wal-e` which I have installed as user root with `sudo python3 -m pip install wal-e[aws,azure,google,swift]`.

I can run this command perfectly as user `root` using `envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env wal-e backup-fetch /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main LATEST`.

However, when I `sudo su - postgres` and then run `envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env wal-e backup-fetch /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main LATEST`, I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/wal-e", line 7, in <module>
    from wal_e.cmd import main
ImportError: No module named 'wal_e.cmd'
```

I gave user `postgres` full sudo permissions with `usermod -aG sudo postgres`.  Also the `wal-e` package is installed in the same location.

When I run `ls -la` I get

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 211 Sep 20 14:24 /usr/local/bin/wal-e`

Im also on Ubuntu 16.04.3

How can I run the command just like the `root` user?

Comment: just to be a 100% sure - you did all these steps (my own installation guide, working on all production servers perfectly)? https://gist.github.com/tschwaerzl/988e618ec6c665fe1a6647ff3f9166ae

Comment: Yep, Im followed those steps more or less. Im using azure so some things were different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to run a [strict setup process](https://gitlab.com/solarisoffgrid-opensource/docker-postgres-wale-azure#restoring-on-a-seperate-machine) for wal-e in order for the package to function properly.

Virtually what it boiled down to was installing all necessary dependencies on the machine that I was working with before installing and creating the user `postgres`. If the user was created before all the dependencies were installed, I got permissions errors.